# Trying to get property of non-object with PHP

Tags: php, yii

I have a strange issue; my code is working on my localhost, but when I try to use it online. It's showing an error in the return line:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Here is the code:

```
public static function displayContenuAsString ($id,$class="traduction survol_video",$div="div") {
        return "<$div id=\"contenu_$id\" class=\"$class\"></$div>".Contenu::model()->findByPk($id)->valeur;     
    }
```

Comment: Does the ID you're trying to retrieve exist in your production database?

Comment: yes i have it's working fine on localhost but problem when i try online.

Comment: well var_dump this one here ... Contenu::model()->findByPk($id)->valeur probably the model did not load correctly.

Comment: Are you sure with the database? Check if your remote database is in sync with your local one. If there's no item with the specified id, there will be no object.

Comment: object was there with the id but the value for the id was not specified in other table

Answer (score 0):

No issues in the code Contenu::model()->findByPk($id)->valeur; Just check for the row in database with primary key.

Comment: thank you  Rajith yah the problem was with the id in the database

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findByPk-detail) `findByPk` return the record found or `Null` if none is found. So you need to add check before using model values in this way:

```
public static function displayContenuAsString ($id,$class="traduction survol_video",$div="div") {
    $contenu = Contenu::model()->findByPk($id);
    $valeur = $contenu !== null ? $contenu->valeur : 'Empty';
    return "<$div id=\"contenu_$id\" class=\"$class\"></$div>".$valeur;     
}
```